# Want to implement Dependency Injection in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, dependencies, code-injection

In an existing WPF application i want to implement dependency injection.
So at the startup of my application i set up the di container and let the window build like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<SplashScreen>().AsSelf();
builder.RegisterType<ILogger>().As(Logger);

Container = builder.Build();

using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
      var window = scope.Resolve<SplashScreen>();
      window.Show();
      window.Initialiseren();
}
```

In my window i have a button that calls another window with multiple dependencies?

```
public partial class AnotherWindow
{
      public AnotherWindow(ILogger)
      {
            ...
      }
}

public partial class Window
{
      public void Button_Click()
      {
            AnotherWindow w = new AnotherWindow(new Logger());
            w.Show();

      }
}
```

How can i use my container to resolve the anotherwindow without passing my container everywhere arround?
My goal is to have ILogger initialized with autofac.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may for example expose the `IContainer` returned from `Build()` using a static property of your `App` class:

```
internal static IContainer Container { get; set; }
```

You could then access it from any view:

```
public void Button_Click()
{
    AnotherWindow w;
    using (var scope = App.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        w = scope.Resolve<SplashScreen>();
    w?.Show();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a really helpfull answer and for the moment i implemented it like this. But i'm concerned that everywhere i go on the internet allot of people are saying that only the startup of the program should access the container? Using a static container is an anti pattern of dependency injection. What is your vision about this?

Comment: I agree but it depends on how you have setup and architected your application. You would generally implement the MVVM design pattern and inject the view model with any dependencies they need instead of using the container explicitly. But your original question was about how to avoid passing the container around.

Comment: But how can you in a wpf application without accessing your container directly or indirectly show a window with dependency injection? I can't really see a way of doing that without calling the container.